# jsf message не отображается (делаю валидатор)

Tags: java, jsf

Есть страница (на которой я делаю тесты)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      lang="ru">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
//всякая всячина
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="id1">
                <f:validator validatorId="imageValidator" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message for="id1" rendered="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Сохранить" />
        </h:form>
//всякая всячина
</h:body>
</html>
```

ее обслуживает бин

```
@ManagedBean(name="Events")
@SessionScoped
@FacesValidator("imageValidator")
public class Events implements Serializable, Validator {
//всякая всячина
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "ахтунг", null);
        throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
    }
}
```

Сейчас хочу добиться что при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить" форма выдает сообщение о ошибки заполнения формы, а далее буду добавлять остальную логику.

В функцию `validate` программа заходит. Выполняет ее без ошибок. Но сообщение не отображается. т.е. `<h:message for="id1" rendered="true" />` как будто не работает. Не пойму в чем дело, вроде все так же как и в примерах делаю.

---

Проблема в том, что primeFaces не дружит с обычным jsf. Т.е. если поменять `<p:commandButton value="Сохранить" />`
 на `<h:commandButton value="Сохранить" />`
то все работает, но не красиво. Буду разбираться ка у primeFaces  валидация работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажатие `h:commandButton` приводит выполнению `POST`-запроса и обновлению страницы целиком, в то время как `p:commandButton` по умолчанию выполняет `AJAX`-запрос, и по умолчанию не обновляет никакие элементы на странице. В `p:commandButton` следует добавить атрибут `update="id1"` для того, чтобы после завершения запроса обновить состояние `h:message`.

Другой вариант - указать атрибут `ajax="false"`. Это приведёт к тому, что поведение `p:commandButton` станет таким же, как у `h:commandButton`.

Comment: хороший ответ..